# Javascript - Sort array with lodash - Get key from inital variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I'm sure, this is a simple question, but actually I can't find a solution. Maybe someone can give me hint.

I have this type of Object array:

```
const Country = {
    albania:
    {
        'iso':'al',
        'countryNo': 70,
        'name': 
        {
            de: 'Albanien',
            en: 'Albania',
            pl: 'Albania',
        },
        'flag':'flag-icon-al',
        'showCountry':true,
    },
    austria:
    {
        'iso':'at',
        'countryNo': 38,
        'name': 
        {
            de: 'Österreich',
            en: 'Austria',
            pl: 'Austria',
        },
        'flag':'flag-icon-at',
        'showCountry':true,
    },
    belgium:
    {
        'iso':'be',
        'countryNo': 2,
        'name': 
        {
            de: 'Belgien',
            en: 'Belgium',
            pl: 'Belgia',
        },
        'flag':'flag-icon-be',
        'showCountry':true,
    },
...
```

The keys of this object are `albania`, `austria`, etc.
Now I want to sort the array. This I'm doing with `lodash` `sortBy` function.

```
let countryList = _.sortBy(Country,'name[' + this.props.currentLanguage + ']');
```

When I iterate through the `countryList` array, how can I get the original keys from the `Country` object array, i.e. `albania`?

I tried to work with `map` function, but then I only get keys named `0`, `1` etc.

```
countryList.map((country,key) => {
    // country -> has all object information
    // key -> 0, 1, 2 etc.
})
```

See the debug picture:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Is there any better solution than this:

```
countryList.map((country,key) => {
    var key = Object.keys(Country).find(function(element) {
        const countryInner = Country[element];
        if(countryInner.countryNo === country.countryNo) {
            return element;
        }
    });
    if(country.showCountry === true) {
        return (
            <HashLink to="/#locations" className={"dropdown-item imageLink animated"} onClick={(e) => this.handleClickCountry(e, key)} key={"nav" + key}>{country.name[this.props.currentLanguage].toUpperCase()}</HashLink> 
        );
    }
})
```

Comment: Note that you don't have any arrays in your input, only objects.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint, but the question is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i will suggest is instead of using lodash , create a 2d array out of your object.Basically move them to an array, sort that array and then rebuild

```
var countryList = [];
for (var con in Country) {
    countryList.push([con, Country[con]]);
}
//Sort based on key value
sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[0] > b[0];
});
```

Once you have the array, you could rebuild the object from the array in the order you like. By this your key wont be lost and you don't have to iterate twice to find that.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When you sort your collection you will lose your object keys, so if it is important for you to keep them after sorting you can add these keys into objects as property you can do it with `map`

```
let countries = _.map(Country, (country, key) => {
    country.key = key;
    return country;
});
```

Now we can sort array again with `sortBy` method of lodash

```
let orderedCountries = _.sortBy(countries, function (country) {
    return country.name[lang]
});
```

where `lang` is one of your language ('de'm 'en', 'pl')...

I believe you also want to filter your list depends on their `showCountry` property so lets merge all of them...

```
function sortAndFilterCountries(countries, lang) {
    countries = _.map(countries, (country, key) => {
        country.key = key;
        return country;
    });
    let orderedCountries = _.sortBy(countries, function (country) {
        return country.name[lang]
    });
    return _.filter(orderedCountries, 'showCountry');
}
```